# Show $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\rho(x)^{-2}dx= +\infty, \hspace{4mm} \forall \epsilon >0$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

let  $\rho(x)=\sqrt{x}, \hspace{4mm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Show :
$$
 \int_{0}^{\epsilon}\rho(x)^{-2}dx= +\infty, \hspace{4mm} \forall \epsilon >0.
$$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\epsilon}\rho(x)^{-2}dx &= \int_{0}^{\epsilon}{1\over x}\,dx\\
&=[ \ln(x) ]_{0}^{\epsilon} \hspace{2mm} \forall \epsilon >0 \\
&=\ln(\epsilon)-\ln(0), \hspace{2mm} \forall \epsilon >0\\
&=\ln(\epsilon), \hspace{2mm} \forall \epsilon >0
\end{align*}
**ln(x)** :Natural logarithm
so i'm stuck help please

Comment: What is $\log(0)$?

Comment: I suppose you have a typo in the last integral you wrote. Would $dx/x$ be better ?

Comment: why are you writing $\rho(x)^{-2}$ instead of just $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @Ant To show you things step by step .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\epsilon}{1\over x}dx = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{y}^{\epsilon}{1\over x}dx = \lim_{y \rightarrow 0^{+}} \ (\log \epsilon -\log y) = + \infty$$

Comment: Thanks so much  now it's pretty clear